# Is there an R Package to read a barcode from an image?

Tags: r, barcode

Im looking for an R Package that can read and extract the data of a barcode of an scanned image.
The barcode is in "Interleaved 2 of 5" format.
Is there any solution in R for this task or do I have to move to Python for this?
I would rather stick to R.

Comment: [`"r" read barcode`](https://www.google.com/search?q="r"+read+barcode) suggested the [`abbyyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/abbyyR/index.html) package, and reading its docs suggested the `abbyyr::processBarcodeField` function. I don't know of others (though I have seen other requests to find one).

Comment: I don't know "r" at all, but the usual go-to-place for simple barcode reading is [ZXIng](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), maybe you can somehow call that ?

Comment: abbyyr uses the Abbyy Cloud Optical Character Recognition (OCR) API. So it needs an internet connection. Unfortnunatley this is not an option for me because I'm working with highly sensitive healthcare data on individual level. R is running on a Laptop that has no acces to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running a python script from the R script.
I used the [reticulate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/calling_python.html) R package which provides an R interface to Python modules, classes, and functions.

The python script example (decode_photo.py) is given below - pyzbar and PIL packages are required:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
def decode_my_photo(file_name):
    result = decode(Image.open(file_name))
    decoded_items =[]
    for x in result:
        decoded_items.append(str(x.data).replace("'","").replace("b",""))
    return(decoded_items)
```

The R script is the following:

```
library(reticulate)

con <- "path_to_barcode_image.png"
use_python("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Anaconda3\\") #can be different
source_python("decode_photo.py")
decoded_value <- decode_my_photo(con)
```